How are keyboard shortcuts linked to vsct commands?
I just dont understand how these (custom?) commands are related to the vsct command file
There is no apparent link between EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Clangd.AllSearch and openAll command id
Yet the menu and the shortcut appears in the code editor... how does this work ?
The command gets registered in C#
private const int OPEN_ALLSEARCH = 0x1234;

registerCommand(OPEN_ALLSEARCH, openAllSearch);

private void registerCommand(int command, EventHandler callback)
{
   var cmd = new CommandID(CommandSet, command);
   var menuItem = new MenuCommand(callback, cmd);
   m_menuService.AddCommand(menuItem);
}

in the .vsct file I see
<Symbols>
   <!-- This is the package guid. -->
   <GuidSymbol name="guidPackage" value="{****************************************}" />

   <!-- This is the guid used to group the menu commands together -->
   <GuidSymbol name="guidPackageCmdSet" value="{****************************************}">
   
      <IDSymbol name="openAll"  value="0x1234" />
      ...

and in the same file, the related button
<Button guid="guidGotoDefentionPackageCmdSet" id="openAll" priority="0x040" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidGotoDefentionPackageCmdSet" id="openMenu" />
    <Strings>
       <ButtonText>All Search...</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
</Button>

How is that above command in the vsct related to this keyboard.vssettings ?
<UserSettings>
    <ApplicationIdentity version="16.0"/>
    <ToolsOptions>
        <ToolsOptionsCategory name="Environment" RegisteredName="Environment"/>
    </ToolsOptions>
    <Category name="Environment_Group" RegisteredName="Environment_Group">
        <Category name="Environment_KeyBindings" Category="{F09035F1-80D2-4312-8EC4-4D354A4BCB4C}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_KeyBindings" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
            <Version>16.0.0.0</Version>
            <KeyboardShortcuts>
                <ScopeDefinitions>
                    <Scope Name="Global" ID="{5EFC7975-14BC-11CF-9B2B-00AA00573819}"/>
                    <Scope Name="Text Editor" ID="{8B382828-6202-11D1-8870-0000F87579D2}"/>
                </ScopeDefinitions>
                <DefaultShortcuts/>
                <ShortcutsScheme/>
                <UserShortcuts>
...
                    <Shortcut Command="EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Clangd.AllSearch" Scope="Text Editor">Shift+Alt+S</Shortcut>
                    <Shortcut Command="EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.Clangd.AllSearch" Scope="Global">Shift+Alt+S</Shortcut>
                    ...
               

thanks for your help

anyone ? this is a complete mystery, I cannot find EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow anywhere online nor in the code
